# How to utilize a CSS button found on the web?

Tags: html, css

How to utilize a CSS button found on the web ?

Hi guys I found a CSS button online and now I try to implement it on my website but I dont understand how do I call the button in my body, here is the code below

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>img_test</title>
  <style type="text/css">
      
      <a href="#" class="myButton">orange</a>

.myButton {
    box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #fff6af;
    background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffec64 5%, #ffab23 100%);
    background-color:#ffec64;
    border-radius:6px;
    border:1px solid #ffaa22;
    display:inline-block;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:#333333;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:15px;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:6px 24px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-shadow:0px 1px 0px #ffee66;
}
.myButton:hover {
    background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffab23 5%, #ffec64 100%);
    background-color:#ffab23;
}
.myButton:active {
    position:relative;
    top:1px;
}

  </style>
</head>

<body>
  
??????

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to put your anchor tag inside the body and not the head. Stuff in the head is not displayed on the screen. Go through [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn) to get a good understanding of the basics.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>img_test</title>
  <style type="text/css">
      
      

.myButton {
    box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #fff6af;
    background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffec64 5%, #ffab23 100%);
    background-color:#ffec64;
    border-radius:6px;
    border:1px solid #ffaa22;
    display:inline-block;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:#333333;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:15px;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:6px 24px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-shadow:0px 1px 0px #ffee66;
}
.myButton:hover {
    background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffab23 5%, #ffec64 100%);
    background-color:#ffab23;
}
.myButton:active {
    position:relative;
    top:1px;
}

  </style>
</head>

<body>
  
<a href="#" class="myButton">orange</a>

</body>

</html>
```